# How to locate a point in z axis given surface location x,y and z and the distance from the first point?

Tags: math, algebra

I have location of a point P1 in x, y and z form. I want to find another point which is directly below this point (in z axis) at a distance d. This means that x & y co ordinates of P2 will be the same as that of P1. How to find the coordinates of P2 (z value)?

Comment: Isn't this simply just `x,y,z-d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the most correct way would be to define a vector for the original point and one for the difference to the other point. Let a, b, c, represent the x, y, z coordinates for the known point and d is the distance of point 2 below point 1, then something like

```
v1 = {a, b, c}
diff = {0, 0, d}
```

and then subtract the two

```
v2 = v1 - diff
```

However, to merely get the coordinates of course all you really need to do is to define

```
v2 = {a, b, c-d}
```

Comment: ok so this means if c is zero (considering this point at ground level 0) and we want to go a distance d below the earth surface the v2 coordinates will be {a,b,-d}?
I was just wondering we need to calculate direction using sin/cos/tan or something? dont we?

Comment: No, it'll not be necessary as long as x,y are constant. We are just moving along a line in the z direction.